# Regular Expressions (regex): /W with hyphen (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate an user input.
The user is allowed to write all characters, digits and "_" or "-".

I'm using

```
myString.search(/\W/) != -1
```

to validate.
It works for everything I want, but not for the "-".
How can I search for "no wordcharacter" but the hyphen "-" is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution should be `myString.search(/[^\w-]/) != -1`

Comment: Range indicators should be + and * if I am not mistaken, it works for me and he could escape it if needed.

Comment: @luastoned inside a character class the `-` is the range indicator you can define ranges e.g. `A-Z` to match every character from A to Z. @T.J. Crowder at the end is also fine.

Comment: It's working, thanks :-)
(You can accept an answer in 7 minutes)

Comment: @stema ah, I was misinterpreting the range part then. Nice to clear that up!

Comment: @stema: Thanks. You're quite right, they even made a note about it in the spec for those who find the grammar confusing (Note 3 on [Section 15.10.2.16](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.16)).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myString.search(/[\W-]/) != -1
```

It's basically matching against a character class that includes any "no word character" and a hyphen.

Comment: @luastoned, which the regex above allows